# regex to string

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to just use the value before the `@` symbol as a value for my `name` during the creation of my ressource. However, I got an error: `Inappropriate value for attribute "email": string required.` my regex is working on the terraform console so I think it's more an error on where I am applying this regex function.

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "account" {
  for_each  = local.all_users
  name      = "${regex("(.*)@", "john.doe@test.com")}"
  email     = "admin@test.com"
  role_name = "Administrator"
  parent_id = var.sandbox_organizational_unit_id
}
```

I also tried `"${tostring(regex("(.*)@", "tom@gmail.com"))}"` and I got a different error, `Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert tuple to string.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
name      = regex("(.*)@", "john.doe@test.com")[0]
```